# Python: How to type hint for an object of any class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In typescript you could type hint for an array of any object:

```
const users: {}[];
```

Or an array of anything at all:

```
const users: any[];
```

How you would type hint for a list of any class in python?

```
users: List[Dict] # like this?
```

Or, if impossible, what about a list of just anything?

```
users: List[any] # something like this?
```

Comment: Did you overlook `typing.Any`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The literal equivalent of Typescript's `any` is `typing.Any`. However, you simply don't need to specify further if you don't want to:

```
users: List
```

This means `users` is a list, but doesn't specify in detail what that list may contain.